# Binding a property of a control within a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

For the purpose of this question, I have defined a very simple user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="simpleUserControl.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Height="300" 
             Width="300">
     <Grid>
         <TextBox Name="TextBox1"/>
     </Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

I want the user (of the user control) to be able to set the 'Text' property of 'TextBox1', so I defined a property (named it 'text') that gets and sets TextBox1.Text:

```
namespace simpleUserControl
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public string text
        {
            get { return TextBox1.Text; }
            set { TextBox1.Text = value; }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty textProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1));

        public UserControl1()
        {                       
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when using the user control , I want to bind this 'text' property to some string object:

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication33.Window1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:simple_user_control="clr-namespace:simpleUserControl;assembly=simpleUserControl"
         Title="Window1" 
         Height="300" 
         Width="300" 
         Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid">
        <simple_user_control:UserControl1 Name="MyUserControl">
            <simple_user_control:UserControl1.text>
                <Binding Path="my_text"/>
            </simple_user_control:UserControl1.text>
        </simple_user_control:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the code behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication33
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string my_text = "this is a text";
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainGrid.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work for some reason... I don't understand why, because I have set the DataContext and put a reference to the user control... What am I doning wrong?
(It is worth mentioning that when setting 'text' property directly like this:

```
MyUserControl.text = "Another text";
```

everything works fine, and therefore I think that that the problem has something to do with the binding).

Comment: It is because the DependencyObject textProperty doesn't automatically inherit the binding context of its parent control.  Therefore your code: <Binding Path="my_text"/> will not return anything.  I am having the same issue and still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a property, you have a private member for `my_text` and WPF won't bind to it.

Try this:

```
private string myText = "this is a text";
public string MyText
{
    get
    {
        return myText;
    }

    set
    {
        myText = value;
    }
}
```

And you should probably implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the setter, if you want to alter the text and display the changes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You were right about implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but There is still something missing.

The code of the main window now looks like this:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    private string _my_text;
    string my_text
    {
        get { return _my_text; }
        set 
        { 
            _my_text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("my_text");
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainGrid.DataContext = this;
        MyUserControl.text = "This is a text";
        my_text = "Another text";  
    }
 }
```

And yet, the only text that appears is "This is a text" and not "Another text".

What's wrong now?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't connected up the `TextBox.Text` property to your dependency property in the user control. Changes in the `DependencyProperty` text will be handled by WPF and won't actually go through your control's text property. You should define your control as follows to bind the `TextBox.Text` property to your dependency property:

```
<UserControl x:Class="simpleUserControl.UserControl1"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 Height="300" Width="300" x:Name="control">
 <Grid>
     <TextBox Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding text, ElementName=control}"/>
 </Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

In the code-behind:

```
namespace simpleUserControl
{
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public string text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(textProperty); }
        set { SetValue(textProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty textProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1));

    public UserControl1()
    {                       
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

Then in your MainWindow you should be able to do this and it should work:

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainGrid.DataContext = this;
    my_text = "This is a text";
    my_text = "Another text";  
}
```